# Error while using agsXMPP in Windows 8 Metro App

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, agsxmpp

I'm using the 'agsXMPP' in windows 8 Metro app,

```
    private void loginclick_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(id.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(id.Text))
            client.Login(id.Text, pwd.Password);
        client.OnLoginResult = success => appendLog("Connection to Facebook established " + (success ? "" : "un") + "successfully");
        client.OnLogout = () => appendLog("Client logged out");
        client.OnMessageReceived = (msg, user) => appendLog(user.name + ":" + msg);
        client.OnUserIsTyping = user => appendLog("The user " + user.name + " " + (user.isTyping ? "started typing" : "stopped typing"));
        client.OnUserAdded = user =>
        {
            appendLog("User " + user.name + " is now available for chat");
            changeContactList(user.name, true);
        };
        client.OnUserRemoved = user =>
        {
            appendLog("User " + user.name + " is not longer available for chat");
            changeContactList(user.name, false);
        };

        txtMsgInput.KeyUp += new KeyEventHandler(txtMsgInput_KeyDown);
    }
```

in the above code an error is coming in this line,

```
    client.OnMessageReceived = (msg, user) => appendLog(user.name + ":" + msg);
```

the error is,

```
    Error   8   The type 'agsXMPP.protocol.client.Message' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'agsXMPP, Version=1.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ff839b81f1debe86'.
```

if I Comment out that line and Execute. It Successfully executes and get the list of available persons on the chat... I checked these links,

http://jefferytay.wordpress.com/2011/12/16/azure-tableservicecontext-presents-an-error-with-createquery-function/

[Strange error w/ NinjectValidatorFactory after updating FluentValidation w/ Nuget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015553/strange-error-w-ninjectvalidatorfactory-after-updating-fluentvalidation-w-nuge)

but can't able to understand, would somebody tell me briefly about this error. . .

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is Because, in this line

```
     client.OnMessageReceived = (msg, user) => appendLog(user.name + ":" + msg);
```

it is saying that reference for msg is missing

or else u use string to replace the agsXMPP.client.protocol.message(i.e., msg). . .